# How to fill textfield

Tags: textfield, fill

Im making a little application, but now im kinda stuck on a small thing here.

I have a jFrame with a list of names, when the user selects a name and press "Change" a new jFrame opens with his Lastname, adress, weight, etc.. But how can i fill in these jTextFields automatically.

```
 if (naam == "Carlos") {
            Information.firstname.setText(name);
            this.dispose();
        }
```

Information = jFrame which opens when name is selected.

Firstname = variable name jTextField.

So here you see what i have so far. Now im looking for a line of code with which you can fill in these jTextFields and jButtons, etc. with pre-written code. Lines which you should place within this if-statement.

i hope to hear from you soon.

Answer (score 0):

Are the user details stored in a database? If so, you should connect the db and then query it to get the last name, address, weight etc automatically. Also naam=="Carlos" won't work. This is String comparison, therefore you should use (naam.equals("Carlos")) instead.